# Recreating The Visual Effect From Super Mario RPG Remake In Unity URP

Tags: unity, graphics, unity-urp

The upcoming remake of Super Mario RPG uses an effect that adds a 'colorful fog'(I'm really struggling to describe it )  to certain parts of the screen. It's mostly used in the corners and top of the screen. I specifically want to replicate how they managed to contain this effect to certain areas of the screen while still keeping other parts' colors saturated and vibrant.

---

Here are some examples of the effect in question:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And here's a link to the game in motion. Some timestamps where the effect is present are:

**1:22, 1:30, 2:07**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-RMxmwtaas

---

Is anyone able to please educate me on what this effect is and how it can be recreated in Unity(URP)?

Thanks so much for taking the time!

Comment: I won't be able to experiment enough to verify an answer, but this looks like a distance or volumetric fog in a purplish hue that's then punched out in a colour grading post-processing pass, mapping the otherwise desaturated greens in the fog back to a greener look.

Comment: It looks like there isn't a clear cut answer for this. The colour grading post-processing sounds like it will make implementing this more involved than I thought... Though, at the very least you've got me researching distance + volumetric fog. Glad I learned these existed!